# What is the invariant of this c++ while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, invariants

I wrote an answer to a problem in a C++ text book, which asked us to make a program that draws a rectangle, square, and triangle. I wrote code that does all these things fine enough, but I am struggling to be able to identify a loop invariant. Some seem straight forward, and others not so much.

The loop scans through the columns of a 20x20 space, based off the height of the triangle, and compares the current column number with a sum and a difference of the height and the row number.

It works, I just don't feel confident that I can identify the invariant.

```
//draws triangle 
int row = 0;
int triHeight = 20;

// invariant: we have written 'row' rows of the triangle
while (row != triHeight)
{
    int col = 0;
    
    //What is the invariant of this while loop? 
    while (col < triHeight + row) {
        
        ++col;
        
        if (col == triHeight - row || col == triHeight + row || row == triHeight - 1)
            cout << '*';
        else {

                cout << ' ';
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    ++row;
}
```

Comment: What is your best guess?

Comment: written 'col' columns so far?

Comment: Which loop are you talking about?  You have two of them.

Comment: My guess would be the part or variables that don't change.

Comment: Five bucks says it the loop underneath the `//What is the invariant of this while loop? ` comment.

Comment: What your meaningful invariants are is best deduced from what's changed inside the loop.  This could incorporate the known state from before the loop, so for example - one invariant for your inner `while` loop is that `col >= 0 && col < triHeight + row`, *iff* there's no weird `int` overflow involved.  That's just a little bit stronger than the `while` condition.  It's possible to have invariants unrelated to the conditions, but your example is kind of boring.  What is always true about the state of `row`, within the inner and outer loops?  Those statements will be additional invariants.

Comment: I appreciate your input Tony, I think I understand a little better now, I had somehow convinced myself that there was _a_ invariant for every loop, and not many possible invariants. I don't know why the rather simple concept of "a property that is true both before and after each iteration" was tricky to me. I really do appreciate folks helping me understand.